# Trigger not working in Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to run below code every hour but it's not working properly. What I mean to say is that when manually run the apps script it's fine but I had gave the trigger for this code as time-driven in every hour.

But this apps script is not updating my spreadsheet on every hour.
Please provide me some solution for this.

```
function gControlMonitoring()
{
    var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    // var ss=sheet.getActiveSheet();
    // var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById('19Fk3pxtfCqP_6Lj-bZvI7UO_ejqA-c1OQBNaBKLa2Tk');
    // SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sheet);
    var ss=sheet.getActiveSheet();
    //  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://mail.google.com/a/advanceforensictools.com");
    Logger.log(resp);
    if(resp.getContentText().indexOf('ssomanagerservlet')>-1)
    {
        var d=new Date();
        var dateformat=Utilities.formatDate(d, "Asia/Kolkata", "MM/dd/yyyy");
        Logger.log("dateformat=" + dateformat); //Taking the Current date 
        // var cell = sheet.getRange(2,1); //updating the spreadsheet with current date 
        // cell.setValue(" " +dateformat);
        var timeFormat=Utilities.formatDate(d, "Asia/Kolkata", "HH");//Taking current Time
        Logger.log("dateTime=" + timeFormat);
        var data_column = ss.getRange(1,1,1,ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();//putting all the values of row one to data_column instance
        Logger.log("record" +data_column);

        if(timeFormat==0)   
        {
            var newrow=updatingspread();//Add New row if a new day has start
            var cell = sheet.getRange(2,1); //updating the spreadsheet with current date 
            cell.setValue(" " +dateformat);  
        }

        for(var i=0;i<25;i++)
        {
            var datacol=data_column[0];
            Logger.log(datacol[i]);
            if(datacol[i]==timeFormat)
            {
                ss.getRange(2, i+1).setBackground('green').setValue(1);
                // if(i==23)
                // {
                //     sheet.getRange(2, i+1).setBackground('green').setValue(1);
                //     var newrow=updatingspread();               
                // }
            }
        }      
    } 
    else 
    {
        for(var i=0;i<25;i++)
        {
            var datacol=data_column[0];
            Logger.log(datacol[i]);
            if(datacol[i]==timeFormat)
            {
                sheet.getRange(2, i+1).setBackground('red').setValue(0);
                if(i==23)
                {
                    ss.getRange(2, i+1).setBackground('red').setValue(0);
                    var newrow=updatingspread();
                }
                GmailApp.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com', 'hello', 'Hello Team');
                Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
                Logger.log(response.getContentText());
            }
        }
    }
}


function updatingspread()
{
    var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = newSheet.insertRowBefore(2);
    var data_column1 = sheet.getRange(2,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getBackgrounds();
    Logger.log(data_column1);
    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
        var dataval=data_column1[0];
        Logger.log(dataval[i]);
        if(dataval[i]!='white'&& dataval[i]!='#ffffff')
        {
            var newup=sheet.getRange(2,i+1).setBackgroundRGB(255,255,255);
        }
    }
    var range = sheet.getRange('A7');
    sheet.hideRow(range);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a function accessing a spreadsheet on a timer trigger you have to use openById("ss id long string") instead of getActiveSpreadsheet and getSheetByName(" sheet name") instead of getActiveSheet  because there is no active spreadsheet in this context.

Comment: Please provide me the exact correction that i should do in this code.

Comment: When I Tried this i got an error ""TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 20, file "Code")"" Please suggest me Something so that i can resolve this error.

Comment: you probably didn't use the right sheet name or spreadsheet ID. Check the values of your spreadsheet.

Comment: I had use the right sheet name and spreadsheet ID . and make the Time Trigger as Every 5 minute .but its not running at every five minute .if i manually run the script its updating the spreadsheet but its not working with trigger .

Comment: if possible to you please provide your email address i will mail all my code with Spreadsheet you can check.

Comment: just make a copy without sensitive data and share it to "anyone with the link can view."